# Display the result from a http post method only for the row on which the button is clicked on in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http, post

I'm new to Angular. I'm trying to start/stop a windows service in .Net using AngularJS.

- UI has server name, status of the windows service and two buttons to start and stop the service.
- On clicking the button, I am passing the server name to the generic start()/stop() which then calls the webmethod on .aspx page.
- That webmethod starts/stops the service and returns the the status of the service.

The problem here is, when I click on first start button, the status column is getting updated for both the servers. 
I'm only expecting the status to be updated on just the row that I clicked on. I think it is just because I am using the same variable `{{retData.result}}` for displaying the result from the http post results. How can I solve this issue? 
Thanks for look into it! Let me know if you need any other details.

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);

angular.module('myApp').controller('AccordionCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $log) {
    $scope.status = {
        isDevOpen: true,
        isTacOpen: false
    };

    $scope.retData = {};
    $scope.retData.Start = function (item, event) {
        $scope.$emit('load')
        $http.post('sample.aspx/Start', { serverName: item })
        .then(function (response, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.retData.result = response.data.d;
            $log.info(response);
            $scope.$emit('unload')
        },function (reason) {
            $scope.error = reason;
            $log.info(reason);
            $scope.$emit('unload')
        });
    }
    $scope.retData.Stop = function (item, event) {
        $scope.$emit('load')
        $http.post('sample.aspx/Stop', { serverName: item })
        .then(function (response, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.retData.result = response.data.d;
            $log.info(response);
            $scope.$emit('unload')
        }, function (reason) {
            $scope.error = reason;
            $log.info(reason);
            $scope.$emit('unload')
        });
    }
}).config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

}).controller('spinnerCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('load', function () { $scope.loading = true });
    $scope.$on('unload', function () { $scope.loading = false });
}]);
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
     <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Server</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
           <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Server1</td>
            <td>{{retData.result}} {{error}}</td>
            <td>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="retData.Start('Server1',$event)">Start</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm " ng-click="retData.Stop('Server1',$event)">Stop</button>
   </td>
         </tr>
      <tr>
           <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Server2</td>
            <td>{{retData.result}} {{error}}</td>
            <td>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="retData.Start('Server2',$event)">Start</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="retData.Stop('Server2',$event)">Stop</button>
   </td>
         </tr>
```

UI
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tat4m.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling the number of servers in the view, you should handle it in the controller. So in your controller you should have something like this after `$scope.status`:

```
$scope.servers = [
    { name: 'Server1', status: 'stopped', error: null },
    { name: 'Server2', status: 'stopped', error: null }
];
```

And then your view will look like this:

```
<tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="server in servers">
         <th scope="row">{{$index+1}}</th>
         <td>{{server.name}}</td>
         <td>{{server.status}} {{server.error}}</td>
         <td>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="start(server,$event)">Start</button>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm " ng-click="stop(server,$event)">Stop</button>
         </td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

All left is to change your `start` and `stop` functions, to something like this:

```
$scope.start = function (item, event) {
    $scope.$emit('load')
    $http.post('sample.aspx/Start', { serverName: item.name })
    .then(function (response, status, headers, config) {
        item.status = response.data.d;
        $log.info(response);
        $scope.$emit('unload')
    },function (reason) {
        item.error = reason;
        $log.info(reason);
        $scope.$emit('unload')
    });
}
```

You don't need the `$scope.retData` so you should remove it and just have the `start` and `stop` functions in your `$scope`.

That's about it.

I'm leaving out a lot of current best practices here, since it would be too big of a topic. I'd advice you to look it up on your own though. I can recommend the [angular styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).